# Getting the private key(p12) from Intel XDK

Tags: ios, macos, cordova, intel-xdk

I used [this tutorial](https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/building-cordova-ios-apps-intel-xdk) to build the iOS app in the intel XDK cloud build. I got the certificate from the Apple Developers site using the CSR that IntelXDK generated and also obtained the provisioning profile from Developers.

So I was able to build and run the file. I'm using `installrapp` and it requires me to upload a `p12 private key` file and I'm not sure where I was supposed to get that. IntelXDK was silent about it and Developers site didn't say much either.

**Please keep in mind that I don't have a Mac that's why I'm using IntelXDK cloud build.**

So is there a way to obtain the private key file using the IntelXDK work-flow or any other which doesn't require a Mac?

Comment: You can create your own P12 file, there are various instructions on the web that explain this. Usually they require that you install openssl to perform that operation. Here's one, for example: https://info.ssl.com/how-to-create-a-pfx-p12-certificate-file-using-openssl/

So you might have to create a P12, upload that to the XDK build system, and then reuse it with the `installrapp` that you are using.

If you are simply trying to get the app installed onto a test iOS device, just email it to your iOS device and click the OTA install link. You have to use the default mail app to make that work.

Comment: But the problem is I couldn't find anywhere to put the p12 file in XDK build system. Have you?

Comment: When you submit iOS certs to the XDK there are two options on the build page (select the "iOS CERTS" tab): 1a and 1b. The instructions for 1b allow you to submit a P12 file. In this case, you do not use the 1a step, you only use the 1b step and submit the P12 file (using the 1b dialog) and then you should be asked for a password for the P12 file.